# How to remove kde plasma login screen

Tags: gnome, kde

I have removed kde plasma not so recently and am troubled with its login screen I should be getting a gnome login screen but get a kde plasma one. How can I remove the kde login screen?I am on 22.04 Ubuntu

Comment: Did you install GNOME? Run the command `sudo systemctl enable gdm.service`

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` should allow you to choose GDM instead of SDDM.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you had installed GNOME properly (if not, install it with `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`).

Now, run the command `sudo systemctl enable gdm.service` to activate the GNOME login screen from the next reboot.

If you are stuck in a SDDM screen and cannot access the terminal, open a virtual terminal with `ctrl + alt + f3`. Enter your username and password to login, and run these commands.